# Is there any way to make the Ubuntu Dash a 'start-up application'?

Tags: unity, login, unity-dash

My desktop is pretty blank and I'd much rather have the useful Dash come up on start-up, is this possible? Surely there is a command that is executed internally when I press the Dash Home button? What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By script, I think it is able. Using `xdotool`, you can simulate keypress event.
Install it by casting : `sudo apt-get install xdotool` on terminal.

1. Open Startup Applications
2. Click 'New' and add `xdotool key Super` on Command field
3. Name the startup item and give comment as necessary
4. Save and try it (I think by relogin is enough)

Super key is default shortcut key to open dash search. Set it to match your setting.

Comment: Since it's just one command, adding it to the Startup Applications will be easier.

Comment: Well, I add more complexity to the easy thing. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Genius, I didn't think anyone would be able to answer this tbh. Thanks! :D (I will try it when I can download packages outside of this blasted school proxy...)

Comment: Can confirm that it works great.